# In Microsoft Edge is it possible for the user to set the point sizes that correspond to HTML small, normal, extra-small, etc?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge is it possible for the user to set the point sizes that correspond to HTML `small`, `normal`, `x-small`, `large`, etc, so that these setting are applied to all web pages?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean the size of the text? If so, go to settings, Appearance.

Comment: I don't see an "Appearances" node in Settings. Maybe the organization where I work is hiding that capability? There's a note in red that says "Some Windows features are only available if you are using a Microsoft account or work account". I have logged in to the app using my work email.   Yes, I do mean setting the font size of the text that corresponds to those HTML relative sizes.

Comment: The organization had an older version of Edge. I got permission to install the newest version and now Appearance is visible in Settings. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't appear that Edge allows you to set the sizes for each of those, or to set the relationship between them, just the base size for normal. If you want more control than that, you may need an extension like Stylus (from the Chrome extension store, not in the Edge extension store).